# How to override default font family Roboto with Poppins in react-native-paper

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbeHw.png)

How to override default font-family Roboto with Poppins in react-native-paper

[i follwed this documentation](https://dev.to/ajmal_hasan/add-custom-fonts-to-react-native-simple-latest-steps-3p23)

Comment: Did you try [this](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/fonts.html)?

Comment: I followed above documentation but i'm getting error message like Unrecognized font family "Poppins-Regular"

Comment: I don't think that font is supported by default. Did you add it as a custom font to react-native? I think [this](https://www.bigbinary.com/learn-react-native/adding-custom-fonts) may work

Comment: Exactly i did same, but it didn't works for me

Comment: Hmm, can you use it in a standard text component?

Comment: Yes i tried that also instead of react-native-paper text component,but...No luck

Comment: Ok, sorry to ask more basic questions, but you didn't really give us a lot of information to start with. How does your `react-native.config.js` look like? And is Poppins-Regular in the fonts directory, you linked there? Also, you could check if the fonts are in `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts` and `Info.plist` in IOS after the link command.